Dataproc Serverless Batch Spark Web UI Not Displaying Executors Logs
I want to run a Spark job using the JDBCToBigQuery template in Dataproc Batch on GCP.
The job runs successfully, but there are no executor logs (stdout, stderr) on the Executors tab in the Web UI like this.

This is the command I used:
gcloud dataproc batches submit spark
    --project PROJECT_ID     \
    --region asia-northeast3    \
    --batch BATCH     \
    --class com.google.cloud.dataproc.templates.main.DataProcTemplate     \
    --version 1.1     \
    --jars file:///usr/lib/spark/external/spark-avro.jar,gs://dataproc-templates-binaries/latest/java/dataproc-templates.jar,gs://MY_BUCKET/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar \
    --subnet SUBNET \
    --service-account SERVICE_ACCOUNT
    --history-server-cluster CLUSTER \
    -- --template JDBCTOBIGQUERY \
    --templateProperty log.level=ALL \
    --templateProperty jdbctobq.bigquery.location=DATASET.TABLE_ID \
    --templateProperty jdbctobq.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://:3306/SCHEMA?user=USER&password=PWD \
    --templateProperty jdbctobq.jdbc.driver.class.name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver \
    --templateProperty jdbctobq.write.mode=Overwrite \
    --templateProperty jdbctobq.temp.gcs.bucket=gs://MY_BUCKET \
    --templateProperty jdbctobq.sql.file=gs://MYBUCKET/test_dataproc.sql \
    --templateProperty project.id=PROJECT_ID 

I wonder how I could show the logs.
I am new to Spark, so I don't know what the problem might be. Previously, I used EMR Serverless, which is also serverless, but I could find the logs there.

Have you checked  Logs Explorer? Please have a look at these link1,link2 and link3.
